# Get records for the nearest date if record does not exist for a particular date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe of stock records, my goal is to pass in a particular 'day' e.g 8 and get the filtered data frame for the 8th of each month and year in the dataset.
I have gone through some SO questions and managed to get one part of my requirement that was getting the records for a particular day, however if the data for say '8th' does not exist for the particular month and year, I need to get the records for the closest day where record exists for this particular month and year.

As an example, if I pass in 8th and there is no record for 8th Jan' 2022, I need to see if records exists for 7th and 9th Jan'22, and so on..and get the record for the nearest date.

If record is present in both 7th and 9th, I will get the record for 9th (higher date).

However, it is possible if the record for 7th exists and 9th does not exist, then I will get the record for 7th (closest).
Code I have written so far

```
filtered_df = data.loc[(data['Date'].dt.day == 8)]
```

If the dataset is required, please let me know. I tried to make it clear but if there is any doubt, please let me know. Any help in the correct direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Alternative 1

Resample to a daily resolution, selecting the nearest day to fill in missing values:

```py
df2 = df.resample('D').nearest()
df2 = df2.loc[df2.index.day == 8]
```

##### Alternative 2

A more general method (and a tiny bit faster) is to generate dates/times of your choice, then use `reindex()` and method `'nearest'`. It is more general because you can use any series of timestamps you could come up with (not necessarily aligned with any frequency).

```py
dates = pd.date_range(
    start=df.first_valid_index().normalize(), end=df.last_valid_index(),
    freq='D')
dates = dates[dates.day == 8]
df2 = df.reindex(dates, method='nearest')
```

##### Example

Let's start with a **reproducible example**:

```py
import yfinance as yf

df = yf.download(['AAPL', 'AMZN'], start='2022-01-01', end='2022-12-31', freq='D')
>>> df.iloc[:10, :5]
             Adj Close                   Close                    High
                  AAPL        AMZN        AAPL        AMZN        AAPL
Date                                                                  
2022-01-03  180.959747  170.404495  182.009995  170.404495  182.880005
2022-01-04  178.663086  167.522003  179.699997  167.522003  182.940002
2022-01-05  173.910645  164.356995  174.919998  164.356995  180.169998
2022-01-06  171.007523  163.253998  172.000000  163.253998  175.300003
2022-01-07  171.176529  162.554001  172.169998  162.554001  174.139999
2022-01-10  171.196426  161.485992  172.190002  161.485992  172.500000
2022-01-11  174.069748  165.362000  175.080002  165.362000  175.179993
2022-01-12  174.517136  165.207001  175.529999  165.207001  177.179993
2022-01-13  171.196426  161.214005  172.190002  161.214005  176.619995
2022-01-14  172.071335  162.138000  173.070007  162.138000  173.779999
```

Now:

```py
df2 = df.resample('D').nearest()
df2 = df2.loc[df2.index.day == 8]

>>> df2.iloc[:5, :5]
             Adj Close                   Close                    High
                  AAPL        AMZN        AAPL        AMZN        AAPL
2022-01-08  171.176529  162.554001  172.169998  162.554001  174.139999
2022-02-08  174.042633  161.413498  174.830002  161.413498  175.350006
2022-03-08  156.730942  136.014496  157.440002  136.014496  162.880005
2022-04-08  169.323975  154.460495  170.089996  154.460495  171.779999
2022-05-08  151.597595  108.789001  152.059998  108.789001  155.830002
```

##### Warning

Replacing a missing day with data from the *future* (which is what happens when the nearest day is after the missing one) is called peak-ahead and can cause *peak-ahead bias* in quant research that would use that data. It is usually considered dangerous. You'd be safer using `method='ffill'`.